Is the deformation of a $C^{\infty}$-manifold over Artin local algebra trivial?
$\DeclareMathOperator\Spec{Spec}$Let $X$ be a compact $C^{\infty}$-manifold without boundary. Let $(A,m)$ be a Artin local $\mathbb{C}$-algebra such that $A/m\cong \mathbb{C}$. Intuitively, a deformation of $X$ over $\Spec A$ is a flat family $\mathcal{X}\to \Spec A$ such that there is a diffeomorphism $\phi: \mathcal{X}\times_{\Spec A}\Spec\mathbb{C}\overset{\sim}{\to} X$.
Since $\Spec A$ consists of only one point, $\mathcal{X}$ is nothing but $(X, \mathcal{O}^{\infty}_{\mathcal{X}})$ where $\mathcal{O}^{\infty}_{\mathcal{X}}$ is a sheaf of flat $A$-algebra on $X$ such that there is an isomorphism of sheaves of $\mathbb{C}$-algebras $\mathcal{O}^{\infty}_{\mathcal{X}}/m\mathcal{O}^{\infty}_{\mathcal{X}}\overset{\sim}{\to} \mathcal{O}^{\infty}_X$.
We call the deformation trivial if we have an isomorphism of sheaves of $A$-algebras $\mathcal{O}^{\infty}_{\mathcal{X}} \overset{\sim}{\to} \mathcal{O}^{\infty}_X\otimes_\mathbb{C} A$.


My question is: Is it always true that a deformation of a $C^{\infty}$-manifold over $A$ is trivial？


I think it is true because the analogous statement about deformation over an small open subset in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is trivial due to Ehresmann's fibration theorem. But I haven't seen a proof for Artin local algebra.

What is "a family" $\mathcal X$? For example, where does this object live?

@Z.M It is just a intuitive definition. We should use the ringed space definition as the true definition.

@ZhaotingWei You need to formalize the question-- this is not a standard context.   (In any formalization you will need to include some sort of flatness condition for the statement to hold).

@PhilTosteson I edited the question, adding the flatness condition. Does it make sense now?

@Z.M: A natural setting would the category of C^∞-schemes.  In fact, the case of C^∞-loci is already meaningful.
